# How can I render user customized views in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a highly customisable software as a service, and I want to be able to let my users create their own custom views for my controller actions.

How can I do it ?

I already have some thoughts about it :

- I could use liquid templates
- I could use a custom mustache approach
- I could develop an api and let the user do all the api calls to my service, which could be pretty difficult, because my clients are not developers.
- I could use https://github.com/apeacox/panoramic

But if someone have done that already, I would love to have feedback.

Thank you so much for your time.
Have a great day !

Answer (score 1):

Liquid was extracted from Shopify for, I would imagine, this exact use case.

http://liquidmarkup.org/

> Liquid is an extraction from the e-commerce system Shopify. Shopify powers many thousands of e-commerce stores which all call for unique designs. For this we developed Liquid which allows our customers complete design freedom while maintaining the integrity of our servers.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to know all my options here to be sure not to dive in too much in one direction, and to waste not too much time.

Comment: Well, evaluating all possible options is a longer write up!

Comment: Agreed :) Thank you for posting this one !